# Why does interface not extend my generic when the same type would?

Tags: typescript

Given a simple type like this

```
type MyType = {
  fundId: string;
  vehicleId: string;
}
```

and this simple test of generic extends

```
type AnyRecord = Record<PropertyKey, unknown>
type TestExtends<T extends AnyRecord> = never
```

Unsurprisingly there is no error passing `MyType` in

```
type Test = TestExtends<MyType> // works
```

However, if I run the same test with `interface` instead of `type`, I get the following error

```
interface MyInterface {
  fundId: string;
  vehicleId: string;
}

type Test = TestExtends<MyInterface>
                         // ^ error here
```

> Type 'MyInterface' does not satisfy the constraint 'AnyRecord'. Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'MyInterface'.(2344)

Can someone explain why this is happening?

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlTkYBXEAE02oC5kBnMKUAcwG4SyA3CABbAEAGwh1GLNiC5EAvkSJh0ABxQYAKqpQBeQj1KUaE5qw7cyyfkNHiGp6bIVLtyAIIh0AJQgIA9lDUyHo%20-oEAPAAKUH5qUMoA0hDoADTIVADWIH4A7iAAfC5qyBoQLACiAB6QNEzhGsgQ1RC17p6hAdT5wcggEPxQisrFpSxaxXqjYFU11HWa2oXDKFPYkLCIuiVl08214RhruJv5QA)

Comment: See [ms/TS#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300) and the answer to the linked question